# Angular 5 Template Variable Error

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 5?
I looked at similar issues on StackOverflow.

I created a module called contact-form.component.html. Everything in the code is ok with no error until I add template variable #firstName="ngModel"

```
        <form>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
         <input ngModel name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" (change)="log()" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group">
         <label for="comment">Comment</label>
         <textarea ngModel name="comment" id="comment" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"></textarea>
         </div>
         <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

error:

```
compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngModel" (" class="form-group">
  <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
  <input ngModel  name="firstName" [ERROR ->]#firstName="ngModel" (change)="log()" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>


This is my app.module.ts:

                    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
            import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


            import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
            import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
            import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
            import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';


            @NgModule({
              declarations: [
                AppComponent,
                CoursesComponent,
                ContactFormComponent

              ],
              imports: [
                BrowserModule
              ],
              providers: [
                CoursesService
              ],
              bootstrap: [AppComponent]
            })
            export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: You should import FormsModule to your module

Answer (score 2):

You must import FormsModule in your AppModule.ts file

```
        import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
        import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
        import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
        import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
        import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
        import { ContactFormComponent } from './contact-form/contact-form.component';
        import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


        @NgModule({
          declarations: [
            AppComponent,
            CoursesComponent,
            ContactFormComponent

          ],
          imports: [
            BrowserModule,
            FormsModule
          ],
          providers: [
            CoursesService
          ],
          bootstrap: [AppComponent]
        })
        export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "XXX"
```

Usually means that you forgot an import.

In your case, you're using `ngModel`. To use ngModel, you need to import `FormsModule` like so

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  // ...
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  // ...
```